# Is it allowed to use a VkBool32 as a push constant?

Tags: c++, glsl, vulkan, spir-v

I am trying to create a VkBool32 in my C++ code:

```
VkBool32 myBool = VK_FALSE;
```

and push it to GLSL via a push constant:

```
vkCmdPushConstants(..., sizeof(myBool), &myBool);
```

which is recieved by a bool inside a uniform storage class:

```
layout(push_constant) uniform PushConstants
{
    bool myBool;
} pushConts;
```

First tests seem to work and have the intended behaviour. But is this permitted by the Vulkan Spec?

Comment: VkBool32 is just an uint32_t so You are just passing a 32-bit uint which is definitely possible. I don't remember how it looks like from the shader's side and it would be good to look at how the bool variable was converted inside the SPIR-V code. Maybe it's also just a 32-bit uint. I will look into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using bools for push constants is fine. There is nothing in the specs that prohibits this and I'v been using it in a few examples too.

If you take a look at the human-readable SPIR-V output you'll see that they're converted to 32 bit integers and thus are aligned to 32 bit:

GLSL

```
layout (push_constant) uniform PushConsts {
    bool calculateNormals;
} pushConsts;
```

SPIR-V

```
 430(PushConsts):             TypeStruct 40(int)
             431:             TypePointer PushConstant 430(PushConsts)
 432(pushConsts):    431(ptr) Variable PushConstant
             433:             TypePointer PushConstant 40(int)
```

So if you e.g. would pass a struct containing multiple booleans you'd have to properly align (pad) on the CPU side before passing as a push constant.

As for the SPIR-V side of things, the [official spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/spir-v/specs/1.0/SPIRV.pdf) is always a good starting point and also contains details on how push constants are handled and how they differ.

Comment: Worth mentioning that care must be taken when pushing such a constant from CPU. If CPU struct looks like struct PC { bool calculateNormals; } and one does PC pc = { false }; followed by vkCmdPushConstants(cmd_buf, layout, VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT, 0, sizeof(PC), &pc), byte 1, 2 and 3 of the push constant as seen by shader would be undefined. So even though byte 0 is 0, due to garbage in other bytes the 'boolean' might evaluate to true.